# JVector Map how to have dynamic images when markers hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

Hi I'm using `JVector Map` and I know my question maybe asked before , and also I found this article [jvectormap markers label image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382954/jvectormap-markers-label-image) too but my problem still not solved

I want to show a picture for each marker in the tool-tip which it shows when mouse hover's it

here is my codes:

```
$('#world-map').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_mill',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    zoomOnScroll: false,
    regionStyle:{
        initial: {
            fill: '#878787',
            "fill-opacity": 1,
            stroke: '#fff',
            "stroke-width": 1,
            "stroke-opacity": 1
        },
        hover: {
            "fill-opacity": 1,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            fill: '#133060'

        },
        selected: {
            fill: 'yellow'
        },
    },
    markerStyle: {
        initial: {
            fill: '#F8E23B',
            stroke: '#383f47',
            "stroke-width": 3,
            r: 10
        }
    },

  markers: [
  { latLng: [61.524010, 105.318756], name: 'FT 1', imgsrc: 'team1.jpg' },
  { latLng: [60.128161, 18.643501], name: 'FT 2', imgsrc: 'team2.jpg' },
  { latLng: [35.861660, 104.195397], name: 'FT 3', imgsrc: 'team3.jpg' },
  { latLng: [37.090240, -95.712891], name: 'FT 4', imgsrc: 'team4.jpg' },
 { latLng: [56.130366, -106.346771], name: 'FT 5', imgsrc: 'team5.jpg' },
  { latLng: [-25.274398, 133.775136], name: 'FT 6', imgsrc: 'team6.jpg' },
  { latLng: [51.165691, 10.451526], name: 'FT 7', imgsrc: 'team7.jpg' },

  ],

  onRegionTipShow: function (e, el, code) {

      el.html(el.html() + '<p id="popop"></p>').css("fontSize","15px");
  },
  onMarkerTipShow: function (e, el, code) {

      el.html(el.html() + '<br /><img src="../Content/img/' + markers[index].imgsrc + '"/>').css("fontSize", "15px");

      //el.html(el.html() + '<br /><img src="../Content/img/' + "team1.jpg" + '"/>').css("fontSize", "15px");
  },


});
```

with this coe it works fine

```
el.html(el.html() + '<br /><img src="../Content/img/' + "team1.jpg" + '"/>').css("fontSize", "15px");
```

but by the guide in that article  I used this one insted because I need diffrent pictures and  it doesn't work .

```
el.html(el.html() + '<br /><img src="../Content/img/' + markers[index].imgsrc + '"/>').css("fontSize", "15px");
```

Appricate if some one help me thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `onMarkerTipShow()` is invoked, the `code` is the `index`, but `markers` are not in scope. You need to get a handle on the `markers` in the map:

```
onMarkerTipShow: function (e, el, code) {
      var markers = $('#world-map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject').markers;  
      el.html(el.html() + '<br /><img src="../Content/img/' 
         + markers[code].config.imgsrc 
         + '"/>').css("fontSize", "15px");
  }
```

Comment: thank you. I solved in another way but this one helps too. thanks

Comment: `el.html(el.html() + '<br /><img src="../Content/img/ourteam/' + markdetail.m[code].imgsrc + '"/><br /><p class="mid">Tourism Expert</p>').css("fontSize", "15px");` this line works too. markdetail is   `var markdetail ={
        m: [
      { latLng: [61.524010, 105.318756], name: 'FT 1', imgsrc: 'team1.jpg' },.....`